# How to permit specific group permissions to project in JIRA

Tags: jira

I am new to JIRA.
I have multiple customers, which I want to have READ only access to their own certain projects. (for instance customer X can access project Y only)
The rest, I dont want them to see.
In addition, I have developers that I want them to have READ/WRITE permissions.

I didn't quite understand the Permissions Schemes and the Roles and the Project setup to create such scenario.

(READ, WRITE permissions I mean for VIEW only and CREATE TICKETS etc...)

Thanks!

Comment: Francis nailed it. Also http://jiradev.blogspot.com/2010/09/jira-groups-and-jira-project-roles.html has more about the difference between JIRA groups and JIRA project roles. ~Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide them only browse permission, but nothing else.
Best is to use project roles to do so, such that you don't need a specific permission scheme per project.

```
- Create a role 'Customer'
- Create a permission scheme 'Customer Project Permission scheme'
- Configure the permission scheme such that
    - The customer role has browse permissions
    - The developer role has all other (applicable) permissions 
        such as edit, move ...
- Link the permission scheme to a project
- Configure the project such that 
    - the userid(s) of your customer(s) appear as a member 
         of the project role 'customer'.
    - the userid(s) of your developer(s) appear as a member 
         of the project role 'developers'
```

Check http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Project+Roles
The Atlassian guys are way better than me to explain this stuff.

Hope this helps,

Francis